# How inflation affects returns and dividends

Tags: investing, dividends, rate-of-return, inflation, dividend-reinvestment

How inflation is linked to returns AND dividends? We know that adj returns are (1+return)/(1+inflation) -1

But how do we account for dividends?

Suppose:
10% annual return
3% inflation
4% dividend yield

Suppose we have 100.000$ invested in year 0. At the end of year 0 we have earned 6.80% ((1+10%)/(1+3%)-1) + 0.97% of dividends reinvested (1+4%)/(1+3%)-1 and so on?

Or do we account dividend yield as it is (4%) without adjusting for inflation, since we have already adjusted the return and then it would be like double counting? (the dividend yield is a function of the price - in this case a function of the asset value - which is already adjusted for inflation)

Thanks all

[image: Plan with dividends]

Answer (score 3):

Note: edits to the question are quickly adding details and changing the validity of my answer here.

Presumably, the dividend is part of the 10% return for the year, no needing to account for it separately. To adjust for “real” return, I’d multiply that $110,000 by .97 and that results in an inflation-adjusted return.

If, in fact, you meant to say that at year end you have an investment valued at $110,000 and $4000 in cash from the dividend, I’d have to change my answer.

Given the comment below, both figures get adjusted, you multiply both the $110,000 in year-end value of the investment and the $4000 in cash by the 3% reduction for inflation. And a 4% dividend is really 3.88% after inflation.

Comment: The second part is what I mean. No need to discuss the generous assumptions here, we all know that 10% yearly and 4% dividends is almost impossible to achieve consistently. I am here to discuss with you guys how and if would you adjust the div yield for inflation, since the return is already adjusted

Comment: I updated my answer per your comment. No debate, just math

Comment: Since dividend _yield_ is a function of _price_, wouldn't it be true that since inflation is already reflected in the price, you'd be double-counting it by applying it to the dividend yield also?

Comment: Only in hindsight. If the dividend yield is stated using the current price/dividend and you are looking back, I can see your point. But that's why the Div Yield is always a moving target. And I suppose the question becomes 4% of what? If it's the price at the start of the time period, I stand by my answer, after the fact, I agree with your math.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer OK I'm with you there.

Comment: @DStanley that is excatly what I meant.

Comment: @DStanley - If my posts are ever ambiguous, that's when an edit would be most welcome and appreciated. It's one thing to think, and quite another to get it in words that are clear.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer i do not agree with your anser. You are referring to a static point (i.e. multiplying the capital eop by 0.97) but this works only for 1 observation. If you have a time series (as in my question) you cannot multiply each end value for 0.97, because you are forgetting the relevance of compounding (the inflation is annual). So, let's take my picture, at year 10 I have 211.280$ capital, inflation adjusted. If i would have take your path, then i would have simply done: 100.000*1.1^10=260.000. And 260.000*0.97 is 251593, which does not take into account the annual inflation

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer at the end my question is simple, and I am sorry if I wasnt that clear before, my bad: what is the final value of an initial investment of 100.000 with annual return of 10%, annual inflation of 3% and annual dividend yield of 4%? Is it 227.690 as I have calculated above? My calculations are correct or do you think there is something I am missing?

Comment: "Unclear' can always be the reader. With the image edited in, I don't see where the .97% dividend comes in, vs the 4% you cited.

Comment: is the formula for the adjusted return (in this case the adjusted dividend yield), as I have pointed out in my question: 1.04/1.03-1

Comment: Joe, what's confusing is combining an inflation adjusted quarterly dividend  with an annual return. The original question and subsequent comments are misleading and confusing and therefore, accurate answers are hard to formulate.

Comment: @BobBaerker - yes, and I don't know how the phrase a clarifying question back to him, too much back and forth already for a simple issue, so, I'm saying he's all yours.

Comment: Joe - Apart from the errant info in the question, the dividend is a distraction which sent the OP off on a wild goose chase. It might add 10-20 basis points of compounding, depending on share price when received and reinvested. That's the only variable in the comparison of a hypothetical non dividend stock yielding 10% EOY to a 4% dividend paying stock yielding 10% EOY (other than dividend taxation if non sheltered). I mentioned in my answer that it would be double counting as did D Stanley about 10 comments back. That's the end of it unless the OP wants to clarify and explain his assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are  double counting.  A dividend is a return of your investment.  It does not provide Total Return because the stock exchanges reduce share price by the amount of the dividend on the ex-div date (as Joe alluded to).

IOW, if you have a 100 shares of a $100 stock worth $10,000 that pays a 4% annual dividend, on the ex-date you will have 100 shares of a $99 stock worth $9,900 and you are due $100 on the Payable Date.  It's the same $10,000 either way, ignoring taxation if non sheltered.  You can't have inflation ravage the $10k as well as the $100 or in the case of your example, ravage the $110k end of year  one Total Return Value and the $1,000 dividend.  It's already included

Where this gets complicated is that with dividend reinvesting, the prices at quarterly reinvestment will vary. OK, you assume constant share price growth and you make that linear to simplify. In addition, you have another complication with the compounding from dividend reinvestment.

The end result is that TR = Dividend + Return from compounding + Position appreciation and the total is 10%.

I'm not  versed in the formulas for this so I'll not offer any solution. But FWIW, the following two web sites agree that $100k with a 4% dividend rate and 3% inflation would turn $100k into $106,796 after one year.  The first one (Zacks)  is the first part of the calculation that you used.  The second gives a 10 year calculation of $192,999 which is less than your numbers:

https://finance.zacks.com/calculate-returns-investments-inflation-1850.html

https://www.americanfunds.com/individual/planning/tools/taxes-and-inflation-calculator/results.htm

Comment: I read the question, and thought OP agreed, He starts year with $100K invested, and ends with $110K in stock plus $4000 cash from dividends. Then he edited an image and updated text to move to annual return of 6.8%, plus a .97% dividend (How did 4%/yr turn into .97?). I am at the point (post edit) where I don't know what the question is, and am likely to delete my own answer in favor of yours. +1

Comment: Joe, From the phrasing, I too wasn't sure about the whole thing so I went with the assumption that 10% was the Total Return which would include the dividend.

Comment: "you have an investment valued at $110,000 and $4000 in cash from the dividend" "The second part is what I mean."  OP then warned me away from questioning such a high assumption. A total 10% wouldn't require any warning. It's lower than history. 14%? That's why he just wanted math. Then div dropped to 1%?

Comment: @joetaxpayer the 6.8% comes from 1.1/1.03-1 and 0.97% comes from 1.04/1.03-1

Comment: @Saverio - Yes, you own a stock worth $100. It give you a $4 dividend on 12/31. Why do you math it so that the $4 in your hand is worth $0.97 vs $3.88?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer because inflation is 3% and dividend is 4%, so real return is about 4%-3%= 1% (0.97% if calculated compoundly)

Comment: I am going to let @BobBaerker take it from here.

Comment: @Saverio - (1) If there was no inflation, how much would  $100k be worth after one year? (2) In your displayed image, why are you combining an inflation  adjusted quarterly dividend of 1% in a line with a 6.80% annual return? Line 0 --> 0 100,000 6.80% .97% 971 107,767 . Regardless of the calculations, that will confuse the reader.